# applicationWillResignActive comes in very late

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background, appdelegate

I've got a strange behaviour: When pressing the power button I'm getting the resign active notification in my app about 1-2 seconds after pressing it. Also when minimizing the app I get the notification very late.

How can I detect my app going to background instantly?
Apps like DM-1 can do it so there must be a possibility.

Hope somebody has an idea!

EDIT: Maybe I should add that I got an NSTimer that does some stuff in the background every second. But the work it does is minimal.

Comment: Your wording is very confusing. You tagged this as an iOS question, so I'm assuming it is. But then you talk about "power button" and "minimizing the app", which would suggest you're talking about an OS X app. iPhones don't have a power button, do you mean the home button? The other one is called sleep button. Also, you can't minimize an iOS app. You either terminate it, or send it to background.

Comment: Hey, sorry to be more precise: I'm talking of the button on top of an iphone / ipad. So sleep button. And on iPad there is this minimization animation when pressing home button. And I get the resign active event at the time when this animation is done.

Comment: If you think you know (or need to know) better than the runtime when notifications should arrive, there is something wrong with your app architecture. Your job is to accept the notifications that *do* arrive, *whenever* they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

This method is called when the user returns to the home screen from your app.

Comment: Resign active gets called before didEnterBackground for me. And both are late.